# Nested navigators inside a custom navigator? Resulting in multiple routers

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a nested PageWithStackNavigator here, inside this code from the React Navigation example for a custom tab view:

```
const CustomTabView = ({ descriptors, navigation }) => {
  const { routes, index } = navigation.state;
  const descriptor = descriptors[routes[index].key];
  const ActiveScreen = descriptor.getComponent();

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <CustomTabBar navigation={navigation} />
      <ActiveScreen navigation={descriptor.navigation} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );;
};


const CustomTabRouter = TabRouter(
  {
    PageWithStackNavigator,
    PageTwo,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'PageWithStackNavigator',
  }
);

const navigator = createNavigator(CustomTabView, CustomTabRouter, {})
const CustomTabs = createNavigationContainer(navigator);
```

But, this is resulting in multiple routers. CustomTabRouter seen here, and one router in PageWithStackNavigator. "this.props.navigation.goBack()" is doing different things depending on if I call it inside the tabs, or inside PageWithStackNavigator.

Per [the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/common-mistakes.html#explicitly-rendering-more-than-one-navigator), I should be doing something like "static router = AuthenticationNavigator.router;", but I don't see how to do this with a custom TabRouter.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not that there were multiple routers, but rather in the goBack command.

From a [comment](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/4546) on my github issue:

> I know this is confusing but you need to use goBack(null). the goBack() helper automatically provides the key that you're going back from and is then limited to the stack that it's inside of. goBack(null) says to go back from anywhere.